# Why is the following readFileSync function returning undefined?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to read files from a folder and then return the result plus some xhtml:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs'),
    files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/files/')

var manifest = function() {
  files.forEach((file) => {
    return `<item href="${file}.html" id="html30" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>`
  })
}

console.log(manifest())
```

`console.log(manifest())` returnes `undefined`, though. Not sure why, since `console.log(contents)` returns the result:

```
foo 1

foo 2

foo 3
```

Comment: Well, your `manifest` function doesn't even have a `return` statement, so what else do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a string from `forEach` isn't going to assign anything since `ForEach` does not produce any side effects. From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

You'll need to `reduce` over your files (into a string) or mutate a variable.

```
var manifest = function() {
  return files.reduce((items, file) => {
    let contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/files/' + file, 'utf8')
    return items + `<item href="${file}.html" id="html30" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>`
  }, '');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! One question: is it necessary to add two returns? Is there a way to have only one return?

Comment: @alexchenco: You can use arrow functions to avoid the `return` keyword.

Comment: Berg I is absolutely right. You can also mutate a variable in a for/forEach loop and then return that if you want to avoid multiple returns. What is your reason for wanting to do so?

Comment: @Bergi I changed `function()` to the arrow function and tried removing the first return and then the second. Returns `undefined`.

Comment: @NickTomlin Okay, I'll try that. It's just to make the code look cleaner. Having two `returns` confuses me a bit.

Comment: Ah. I personally prefer the returns over an interstitial variable but I understand if you think differently :)

Comment: @alexchenco: Well, you've got two functions, each of which should return something. If you're confused by that, I'd recommend to use a `for of` loop instead of `.forEach()`